# Production schedule using MS Project 2007

Tags: project-management, microsoft-project

OK... I am new to MS Project.  My charge is to have this program schedule a multi-project workflow where the task are always the same .. just different durations.  The task are also always linked in the same order as it is similar to as assembly line production process.

Would someone please help me get my footing.  I need to fill out the durations for each new project and have Project 2007 add it to the backlog mix and provide me with an estimate delivery date.  Here are my problems.

I'm starting to believe that "Priority" is just a relative guideline as opposed to a strict rule governing the order of completion. True?  If true is there a whay to accomplist a hard priority listing?

I can't figure out how to have Project fully allocate my multi-person department resources. My resources are departments set and 100% for 1 person, 200% for 2 people, etc. (as opposed to assigning individuals to each task).  When I bump up the percentage (add a person) the schedule does not change.  Why?

Any pointers are most appreciated.  We run 40 to 50 concurrent projects with the same resources.  Delivery dates are always a mystery as each project is different (6 weeks to 12 months in duration).

Thanks a bunch!
John

Answer (score 1):

Priority field is used when performing task leveling with MS Project, so higher priority tasks will be scheduling first, if possible.

Don't rely on the tool to make the task scheduling for you automatically. I use the view called Detail Gantt, which displays the slacks available for tasks, and I move the task by hand to solve the overallocations.

However, if you have 40-50 concurrent projects with the same resources and you are trying to optimize resource allocation between them, I am not sure that MS Project is the right tool to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure microsoft project is the best software for what you need, and it is not very flexible. I personally use custom excel spreadsheet to do the calculation of my tasks and I use MS Project to make a visualisation with calendar and gantt for the team,

Still, if you have multiple project with similar description, start by making one correctly and then copy paste for the other projects, changing only what you need.

To make hard prioritization use the dependecies. Keep the priority for the task that can be concurent.

For your problem with 200%, I think this is in the project settings.

Comment: Do you have a spreadsheet you would be willing to share?  I thought of writing one but decided to try Project 2007 first.

Comment: I can't share it, but it wouldn't fit your need anyway. We usually make the first column timeline. It's very easy to do scripting in excel with VB. There are also sheets you can download on many web sites on management.